# Configuration for SQL Server Based Assembly

Tags: .net, sql-server, configuration, clr

I have an assembly deployed to SQL Server that performs an export to an accounting system SDK.  The **reasons** that this is deployed to SQL Server are **beyond my control**, and I **cannot modify** the target **database**.

In development, I moved several dynamic queries from hard-coding to text files outside the application, so that queries can be tweaked if necessary after deployment.  Is there a way I can 'inform' my assembly as to the location of these text files on the server machine, without using a database field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding the text files to the project as <strike>embedded</strike> resources is a better avenue to follow.  This absolves the deployer of any responsibility for configuring the assembly or deploying the text files.

Comment: This does reduce the accessibility of the files for maintenance, but I can automate a rebuild for support, with them only having access to the query files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the path of text files from some well know locations like:

- registry
- application local storage
- predefined directory